# GSAP TweenLite not animating basic quickstart example

Tags: javascript, dom, gsap

I'm trying to get started with GSAP, but can't seem to get anything working yet. I've included TweenLite, the Easing and CSS plugins, and have very basic code, but I can't seem to get anything running. Here is my main javascript:

```
window.onLoad = function(){
  var logo = document.getElementById("logo");
  TweenLite.to(logo, 1, {
    left: "632px",
    onComplete: function(){
      console.log("completed anim");
    }
  });
}
```

You can see a running example at [deconfigured.com](http://deconfigured.com) (at the time of this post, it's on a personal server. I'll transfer it over to a jsfiddle after I make sure that my server software isn't the cause of the issue).

The console log never appears on my browser (latest firefox).

Is it just a silly error? Any help would be tremendous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `window.onload`, without caps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload